# How to write an empty list using S, K and I combinators?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, lambda, lambda-calculus

I know that:

```
(cons [p] [q]) is ((s ((s i) (k [p]))) (k [q]))
(car [lst]) is ([lst] k)
(cdr [lst]) is ([lst] (k i))
```

I want to write a list like this

```
(cons [a] (cons [b] (cons [c] [nil])))
```

, which is going to be something like this:

```
((s ((s i) (k [a]))) (k ((s ((s i) (k [b]))) (k ((s ((s i) (k [c]))) (k [nil]))))))
```

But I don't know how to compile 'nil' into S, K and I combinators. Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance,
Edwin Jose Palathinkal

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~gam23/teaching/ProgrammingIII/10lambdaprogramming.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you need from a `nil` representation is to be able to identify it -- write some `null?` predicate that returns "true" for `nil` and "false" for all other pairs.  This means that the answer depends on your representation of true/false.  With the common choice of `λxy.x` and `λxy.y`, a convenient encoding for `nil` is `λf.[true]`.  Translating this to SKI is very easy now (and I won't do it here, since it looks like homework...).

(Also, implementing a `null?` predicate given this representation for `nil` is a good exercise.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Edwin Jose Palathinkal.